# Why Duplicate Events are adding While updating the Event in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ekevent

I have an event from 16 Feb, 2015 to 20 Feb, 2015 at 10AM with an alarm set to it.

It is saved fine at calendar. When I update my event like time from 10AM to 2AM. It is updating at calendar also.

But from 17 Feb, 2015 to 20 Feb, 2015 the event is adding with 9AM(expected) and also with 12AM(Duplicate Event of above) is adding.

So when ever I am updating the events From date to To date the duplicates is adding with 12AM time.(Every time event with 12AM is adding to calendar along with original event)[image: Duplicate Calendar Events Image]

Here is my code for Updating the existing event

```
EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:self.eventStore];
event = [self.eventStore eventWithIdentifier:eventIdentifierOfExisting];
event.title = @“Calciferol”;    
    event.startDate = pickerFirstAlarm.date;//firstcombDate
    event.endDate = pickerEndDate.date;

    if ([btnEndDate.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Select"]) {
        EKRecurrenceEnd *endRecurrence = [EKRecurrenceEnd recurrenceEndWithOccurrenceCount:14];//EKRecurrenceFrequencyDaily
        EKRecurrenceRule *rule = [[EKRecurrenceRule alloc] initRecurrenceWithFrequency:EKRecurrenceFrequencyDaily interval:1 end:endRecurrence];
        [event addRecurrenceRule:rule];
    }
    event.notes = @“Calcium”;
    NSTimeInterval aInterval = -5 *60;
    EKAlarm *alaram = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:aInterval];
    [event addAlarm:alaram];
    [event setCalendar:self.defaultCalendar];
     if (event.availability != EKEventAvailabilityNotSupported) {
         event.availability = EKEventAvailabilityFree;
     }
     NSError *err = nil;
    [self.eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];
```

Have anyone observed this issue..

Please suggest where I am going wrong..

Thanks In Advance..!

Comment: Did you ever manage to resolve this issue?